# Checking if Tkinter Widget (OptionMenu) is disabled

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, optionmenu

I feel like I've scoured the web for an eternity, rephrased my question a thousand times for something I feel like should be very simple.

I wonder if there is a way to check if a Tkinter Widget is active (not greyed out / disabled). I have a set of OptionMenus that start out disabled, and are configured to `state=ACTIVE` when they click a checkbox, so that the user can select which OptionMenus they want to use.

When I try to "submit" the fields in the OptionMenus, I only want the ones that are `ACTIVE`. I already tried `if OptionMenu.state == ACTIVE` but then I get an error that OptionMenu has no attribute state, even though I configure that earlier.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
from tkinter import *    

class Application(Frame):
    # Initializing the window and the required variables
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.checkbox_in_use = BooleanVar(self, False)
        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="check", 
                                    var=self.checkbox_in_use, 
                                    command=self.check_change
        self.checkbox.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W')

        self.menu = OptionMenu(title_setting,
                               "Menu",
                               "Menu",
                               ["Menu1", "Menu2"])
        self.menu.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.menu.config(state=DISABLED)

        submit = Button(self, text="submit", 
                        command=self.submit_function)
        submit.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    # Initialize the window
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Example")

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    def check_change(self):
        if self.checkbox_in_use.get():
            self.menu.config(state=ACTIVE)
        else:
            self.menu.config(state=DISABLED)

    def submit_function(self):
        # This is the part I want to do something with.
        if self.menu.state == ACTIVE:
            print("You are good to go! Do the stuff.")


root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x300")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for all responses.

Comment: To get the value of a configured attribute, use the `cget` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `cget()` for this. `self.menu.cget('state')` will do the trick.

That said I want to point out some other things in your code.

You `Application` class already has an `__init__` at the start so why use:

```
# Initialize the window
def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("Example")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

You really should not pack the frame from inside the frame class but rather when calling the class. Also pack wont work here it will throw an error. Do this instead: `app = Application(root).grid()`.

Take a look at the reformatted example below (with `cget()`).

```
from tkinter import *    

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.checkbox_in_use = BooleanVar(self, False)
        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="check", var=self.checkbox_in_use, command=self.check_change)
        self.checkbox.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W')

        self.menu = OptionMenu(master,"Menu","Menu",["Menu1", "Menu2"])
        self.menu.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.menu.config(state=DISABLED)

        Button(self, text="submit", command=self.submit_function).grid(row=2, column=0)

    def check_change(self):
        if self.checkbox_in_use.get():
            self.menu.config(state=ACTIVE)
        else:
            self.menu.config(state=DISABLED)

    def submit_function(self):
        print(self.menu.cget('state'))


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Application(root).grid()
root.mainloop()
```